# How do I get to display a Var into a label by pressing a button in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a new Tkinter user, but I want to use the *.get* method to take two entries from 2 entry widgets and get their mean and standard deviation which are also displayed into 2 other labels. The problem is that, I have failed to display the mean and standard deviation. It has also failed to display the parameter returned, when the SD Zone button is clicked. Some help please. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, ttk
import random
import datetime


#====================Root of the app======================================
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300+0+0")
root.title("SD zone finder")
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
#Top frame that has the widgets
Topframe = Frame(root, width = 500, height = 265, bd = 5, relief = 'raise')
Topframe.pack(side = TOP)

#Bottom frame just to display my name
Bottomframe = Frame(root, width = 500, height = 50, bd = 5, relief = 'raise')
Bottomframe.pack(side = BOTTOM)

labelbottom = Label(Bottomframe, font = ('garamond', 12, 'italic'), width = 60, text = "Muhammad", justify = 'center')
labelbottom.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

#========================Input Variables==============================
#These the the input and out put variables for the labels and entry widgets
var1 = DoubleVar()
var2 = DoubleVar()
var3 = DoubleVar()
var4 = DoubleVar()
var5 = DoubleVar()
var6 = StringVar()

var1.set("0.0")
var2.set("0.0")
var3.set('mean')
var4.set('std_dev')
var5.set("0.0")
var6.set('y')
#These are the formulae for mean and standard deviation for floats entered in the entry widgets
mean = float((var1.get())+(var2.get())/2)
std_dev = float((((var1.get())-mean)**2+((var2.get())-mean)**2)/(2-1)**(1/2))
y = float(var5.get())
#=====================Button Press Functions=================================
#This is the function that is to be called when user clicks the Mean and SD button
def stats():
    var3.set(mean)
    var4.set(std_dev)

#This is the function to call when the user clicks the SD Zone button
def sdzone():
    if y == mean:
        var6.set("Along mean")
    elif mean > y < ((1/2)*std_dev):
        var6.set("+0.5SD")
    elif (mean+((1/2)*std_dev)) > y < (mean+std_dev):
        var6.set("+1SD")
    elif (mean+std_dev) > y < (mean+1.5*std_dev):
        var6.set("+1.5SD")
    elif (mean+1.5*std_dev) > y < (mean+2*std_dev):
        var6.set("+2SD")
    elif (mean+2*std_dev) > y < (mean+2.5*std_dev):
        var6.set("+2.5SD")
    elif (mean+2.5*std_dev) > y < (mean+3*std_dev):
        var6.set("+3SD")
    elif mean > y > (mean-(1/2)*std_dev):
        var6.set("-0.5SD")
    elif (mean-(1/2)*std_dev) > y > (mean-std_dev):
        var6.set("-1SD")
    elif (mean-std_dev) > y > (mean-1.5*std_dev):
        var6.set("-1.5SD")
    elif (mean-1.5*std_dev) > y > (mean-2*std_dev):
        var6.set("-2SD")
    elif (mean-2*std_dev) > y > (mean-2.5*std_dev):
        var6.set("-2.5SD")
    elif (mean-2.5*std_dev) > y > (mean-3*std_dev):
        var6.set("-3SD")
    else:
        var6.set("Out of 3SD")

#=======================Stats Labels========================================

#These are the widget details for labels and entry fields
Run1Label = Label(Topframe, font = ('garamond', 14), height = 2, text = "Enter first run here:",  justify = 'left')
Run1Label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)

Run2Label = Label(Topframe, font = ('garamond', 14), height = 2, text = "Enter second run here:",  justify = 'left')
Run2Label.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

MeanLabel = Label(Topframe, font = ('garamond', 14), height = 2, text = "The mean is:",  justify = 'left')
MeanLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

SDLabel = Label(Topframe, font = ('garamond', 14), height = 2, text = "The SD is:",  justify = 'left')
SDLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 3, sticky = W)

#==========================SD Zone labels===================================
DailyrunLabel = Label(Topframe, font = ('garamond', 14), height = 2, text = "Enter QC run here:",  justify = 'left')
DailyrunLabel.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)

SDzoneLabel = Label(Topframe, font = ('garamond', 14), height = 2, text = "The SD zone is:",  justify = 'left')
SDzoneLabel.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)

#=======================Stats Entries and Displays==========================
Run1entry = Entry(Topframe, font = ('garamond', 14), width = 10, bd = 5, textvariable = var1,  relief = 'sunken')
Run1entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)

Run2entry = Entry(Topframe, font = ('garamond', 14), width = 10, bd = 5, textvariable = var2,  relief = 'sunken')
Run2entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)

Dailyrunentry = Entry(Topframe, font = ('garamond', 14), width = 10, bd = 5, textvariable = var5,  relief = 'sunken')
Dailyrunentry.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)

Mean2Label = Label(Topframe, font = ('garamond', 14), width = 7, bd = 5, textvariable = var3,  relief = 'sunken', anchor = 'w')
Mean2Label.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

SD2Label = Label(Topframe, font = ('garamond', 14), width = 7, bd = 5, textvariable = var4,  relief = 'sunken', anchor = 'w')
SD2Label.grid(row = 2, column = 4, sticky = W)

SDzoneLabel = Label(Topframe, font = ('garamond', 14), width = 7, bd = 5, textvariable = var6,  relief = 'sunken', anchor = 'w')
SDzoneLabel.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)

#=====================Buttons===============================================
#These are the two buttons of the app
StatsButton = Button(Topframe, font = ('garamond', 14), width = 10, height = 2, bd = 5, text = "Mean and SD", command = stats())
StatsButton.grid(row = 0, column = 4, rowspan = 2)

SDButton = Button(Topframe, font = ('garamond', 14), width = 10, height = 2, bd = 5, text = "Find SD Zone", command = sdzone())
SDButton.grid(row = 3, column = 4, rowspan = 2)




root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons aren't working properly.

When you're calling a function from a button it shouldn't be

```
command = foo()
```

Instead it should be

```
command = foo
```

If you want to send parameters into a function from a button you can use [lamda](https://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php)

```
command=lambda: foo(x)
```